# Constant initialisation from a user-made function synthesis takes forever but easily created in simulation

Tags: vhdl, fpga, xilinx, vivado

I have created a function "my_func" in a package which when inputted with x produced a matrix of integers of shape [log2(x), x]. I wish to place this slice into ROM memory for synthesis.

For the sake of synthesis I attatch a counter to the ROM and read out one register per clk cycle. I have been able to simulate this and get the expected answers. The synthesis of the code never finishes, even when the generic controling the function is very small as shown in the code.

I am confused as to why Vivado can very quickly simulate the desired design but takes forever to synthesise. I get no errors from vivado saying that the design is unsynthesisable.

Has anyone else experienced this problem, and what are the steps I can take to avoid the problem in the future?

Please see my synthesis code below and a snippet of the function code below

For the record for this question Synthesis = Elaborate Design (RTL)

```
library IEEE;
library WORK;
use WORK.mylib.all;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;
use IEEE.math_real.all;

entity try is
    generic(
    x : integer := 8
);
    port(
    clk : in std_logic;
    ouput: out integer;
);
end entity try;

architecture v1 of try is
    constant sig : my_matrix_of_integers(0 to integer(log2(real(x)))-1, 0 to x-1) := my_func(x);
    signal counter : unsigned(integer(log2(real(x)))-1 downto 0);
    begin
        process(clk)
        begin
            if rising_edge(clk) then
                output <= sig(0, to_integer(counter));
                counter <= counter + 1;
            end if;
        end process;
end architecture v1;
```

Here is a snippet of my function code

```
function my_func (x: integer) return mat_t is
    variable y: integer := integer(log2(real(x)));
    variable cluster : integer;
    variable index : integer;
    variable mat : my_matrix_of_integers(0 to y-1, 0 to x-1);
begin
    for s in 0 to y-1 loop
        index := x/(2**(s+1));
        cluster := x/index;
        for c in 0 to cluster - 1 loop
            for i in 0 to index -1 loop
                if c mod 2 = 0 then
                   mat(s, (c*index) + i) := 0;
                else
                   mat(s, (c*index) + i) := i*(2**(s));
                end if;
            end loop;
        end loop;
    end loop;
    return mat;
end function my_func;
```

and type ...

```
type my_matrix_of_integers is array(integer range <>, integer range <>) of integer;
```

Comment: Please can you supply an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Then I can have a play.

Comment: @MatthewTaylor the rest of the code has been added. just add the type before the function in the architcture

Comment: You're using a 2D array for the ROM. I dont know any tool that officially supports 2D arrays when infering memory elements, so it is likely building the entire ROM out of luts/registers, which will take a loooong time to synth (plus vivado probably the worst engine for infering anything!). Simulation is quick because its perfectly normal and simple code - its not doing a gate simulation.

Comment: I've had a play and cannot get Vivado to infer a ROM from your code. But, as I tell my customers, if you want your FPGA synthesiser to infer a memory, you need to read the instructions for your synthesiser. I had a look at the Vivado instructions and discovered an atrribute that perhaps ought to be set: `rom_style`, but that still didn't help in this case. I tried changing the array to an array of an array (which requires VHDL 2008), but Vivado doesn't support that aspect of VHDL 2008. So, I think you'll need to go back a few steps and rewrite your code.